# Swagger Spring API

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Spring Swagger library v1.0.2

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am able to scan my REST APIs and view it on the Swagger UI. I have even implemented OAuth and it is working great.

However, there is one feature that I need to implement. I want to hide some of the REST APIs. I need to do this at the class level as well as on the method level. I read about an 'hidden' attribute in the @Api annotation. I set it to 'true' but I can still see my class and all its method being displayed in the Swagger UI.

Example:

```
 @Api( 
        description="This class is not covered by Spring security.", 
        value="/unauthorize",
        hidden=true)
 @RequestMapping("/unauthorize")
 @Controller
 public class UnauthorizeResource {}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can prevent the 'UnauthorizeResource' class from being displayed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can utilize the [`@ApiIgnore`](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/80#issuecomment-32139138) annotation:

```
@ApiIgnore
@RequestMapping("/unauthorize")
@Controller
public class UnauthorizeResource {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Accepted it as an answer.